# Convert findstr batch file to Web Search Box

Tags: html, batch-file, search, web, command-line

I have the following code in a command line batch file that I would like to convert to a web application search box. Then display results in a new tab when clicking submit.  Everything I've found for search boxes either searches google, searches text on screen, or requires creating a database instead of searching for text within various "log" text files.

**I'm curious which language would be the best for converting this code to a web search box?  Would anyone be able to provide examples in maybe javascript, php, perl, or other language?**

Thanks,

```
set webServerPath=

echo -- Name --

set /p name=": "

findstr /r /i "%name%" %webServerPath%\CopiedMovedFiles\ *.txt>%webServerPath%\Found.txt

findstr /r /i "%name%" %webServerPath%\TarPackages\ *.txt>>%webServerPath%\Found.txt

findstr /r /i "%name%" %webServerPath%\TaskErrors\ *.txt>>%webServerPath%\Found.txt

Start notepad.exe %webServerPath%\Found.txt

pause
```

Comment: Your batch file has basic issues - what is it that you want to search in this app?  The same files you are searching in the batch script?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The echo name was just to display notifying to input the name.  The findstr are looking for text within the files in each directory.  I was hoping to develop a way to search then display those found text strings in web form.  Also, I put spaces before the * because this form wasn't displaying the \.  Also, exploring php forms now to possibly have the batch run as a scheduled task run using information from a submitted php form then using blat to email out instead of opening notepad.

Comment: What is a 'web form' when displaying text strings?  Do you just want the text displayed in a browser window instead of notepad?

Comment: I was hoping to build a search box on a web page that I could you instead of this batch file but would act the same way and then display the results in a new browser tab.

Comment: Just clarifying, do you want people to search the files remotely, over the internet using their web browser?

Comment: Yes is that something that can be created easily without a database?

Comment: I believe you will need server side software too.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I was afraid of.  I think by the time I either author a batch file to run as a scheduled task on the sever or utilize software, it would probably be better to create a database.  Engineering at my work is planning to do upgrades on this workflow next year so I'll follow up with them at that point.